# How to eliminate date islands in a logging table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a logging functionality that is executed on each start and end of a table transfer process. It creates a separate entry for both start and stop:

[image: Visualization of start and stop]

Between each distinct table transfer there is a DB restore process that is not logged:
[image: Visualization of DB restore in gap between two processes]

There is no feasible pattern in the execution (log) times that I can use and base my DATEDIFF on.

I have two questions:

1. How do I unite the logs for the TransferingTables process so that each logid line represent the proces start and end, opposite to two lines as is now?
2. How do I create an entry for the DB restore process that is not being logged?

Sample DDL and DML:

```
    CREATE TABLE #temptableTimeStamps
(
    [logid] INT,
    [procesid] INT,
    [Object] VARCHAR(17),
    [Started] DATETIME2(7),
    [Finished] DATETIME2(7)
);
INSERT INTO #temptableTimeStamps
(
    logid,
    procesid,
    Object,
    Started,
    Finished
)
VALUES
(1, 00000000, 'TransferingTables', N'2020-11-01T04:19:20.2666667', N'2020-11-01T04:19:20.2666667'),
(2, 00000000, 'TransferingTables', N'2020-11-01T20:23:36.39', N'2020-11-01T20:23:36.39'),
(3, 00000000, 'TransferingTables', N'2020-11-01T22:09:13.5766667', N'2020-11-01T22:09:13.5766667'),
(4, 00000000, 'TransferingTables', N'2020-11-02T03:48:34.6733333', N'2020-11-02T03:48:34.6733333'),
(5, 00000000, 'TransferingTables', N'2020-12-01T12:08:15.8466667', N'2020-12-01T12:08:15.8466667'),
(6, 00000000, 'TransferingTables', N'2020-12-01T15:31:42.4633333', N'2020-12-01T15:31:42.4633333'),
(7, 00000000, 'TransferingTables', N'2020-12-01T17:13:04.26', N'2020-12-01T17:13:04.26'),
(8, 00000000, 'TransferingTables', N'2020-12-01T20:16:52.25', N'2020-12-01T20:16:52.2633333'),
(9, 00000000, 'TransferingTables', N'2020-12-14T16:32:22.96', N'2020-12-14T16:32:22.96'),
(10, 00000000, 'TransferingTables', N'2020-12-14T23:08:09.5566667', N'2020-12-14T23:08:09.5566667'),
(11, 00000000, 'TransferingTables', N'2020-12-15T01:15:24.3766667', N'2020-12-15T01:15:24.3766667'),
(12, 00000000, 'TransferingTables', N'2020-12-15T11:39:43.1733333', N'2020-12-15T11:39:43.1733333');
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5a777/2)

Comment: Please don't post images of data; include it in a consumable format. SQL Fiddle doesn't load for me (and I would assume others) so if you have included the DDL and DML for your tables, you should also include it in the question. Fiddles should *complement* the question, not be required to be able to answer it.

Comment: First of all, seeing your data you couldn't be sure if a record is an start or and end, so I recommend that the started column would be used for keep the time of start events and the finished the finish of the event and keep null the column donn't being used

Comment: Because you could add `CASE WHEN row_number() over (order by finished)%2=1 THEN 'Start' ELSE 'Finish' END as Status` to your query ([FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5a777/4)), still does not mean that this would be a nice/good solution.....

Comment: Not an answer to the question but the letter r appears twice in the word transferring. Sorry I am cursed that misspelled words jump off the page at me.

Comment: @SeanLange Don't you mean 3 times?  :)

Comment: @JonArmstrong indeed!!! Thanks for correcting my pedantic correction. :D

Answer (score 0):

I believe I understand the logic you are trying to do, but here are examples outlined below to confirm

The start/stop of the first transfer process:

- Begins at [Started] from row LogID = 1
- Ends at [Finished] from row LogID = 2

The start/stop for the first restore process:

- Begins at [Finished] from row LogID = 2
- Ends at [Started] from row LogID = 3

### Track Start/Stop of Each Process in 1 Row

```
;WITH cte_RowNumber AS (
    SELECT RowID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Started])
        ,*
    FROM #temptableTimeStamps
),
Cte_Restore AS (
    SELECT A.*
        ,TransferStarted = CASE WHEN RowID % 2 = 1 THEN [Started] END
        ,TransferCompleted = Lead(Finished) OVER (PARTITION BY [Object],ProcesID ORDER BY LogID)
        ,DbRestoreStarted = CASE WHEN RowID % 2 = 0 THEN Finished END
        ,DbRestoreCompleted = Lead([Started]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Object],ProcesID ORDER BY LogID)
    FROM cte_RowNumber AS A
)
SELECT NewRowID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LogID) 
    ,A.[Object]
    ,B.*
FROM Cte_Restore AS A
CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('Transfer',TransferStarted,TransferCompleted)
                ,('Restore',DbRestoreStarted,DbRestoreCompleted)
            ) AS B(Activity,StartDatetime,EndDatetime)
Where StartDatetime IS NOT NULL
    --AND EndDatetime IS NOT NULL /*Use this to filter out last restore row with no end date yet*/
ORDER BY NewRowID
```

### Results:

| NewRowID | Object | Activity | StartDatetime | EndDatetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TransferingTables | Transfer | 2020-11-01 04:19:20.2666667 | 2020-11-01 20:23:36.3900000 |
| 2 | TransferingTables | Restore | 2020-11-01 20:23:36.3900000 | 2020-11-01 22:09:13.5766667 |
| 3 | TransferingTables | Transfer | 2020-11-01 22:09:13.5766667 | 2020-11-02 03:48:34.6733333 |
| 4 | TransferingTables | Restore | 2020-11-02 03:48:34.6733333 | 2020-12-01 12:08:15.8466667 |
| 5 | TransferingTables | Transfer | 2020-12-01 12:08:15.8466667 | 2020-12-01 15:31:42.4633333 |
| 6 | TransferingTables | Restore | 2020-12-01 15:31:42.4633333 | 2020-12-01 17:13:04.2600000 |
| 7 | TransferingTables | Transfer | 2020-12-01 17:13:04.2600000 | 2020-12-01 20:16:52.2633333 |
| 8 | TransferingTables | Restore | 2020-12-01 20:16:52.2633333 | 2020-12-14 16:32:22.9600000 |
| 9 | TransferingTables | Transfer | 2020-12-14 16:32:22.9600000 | 2020-12-14 23:08:09.5566667 |
| 10 | TransferingTables | Restore | 2020-12-14 23:08:09.5566667 | 2020-12-15 01:15:24.3766667 |
| 11 | TransferingTables | Transfer | 2020-12-15 01:15:24.3766667 | 2020-12-15 11:39:43.1733333 |
| 12 | TransferingTables | Restore | 2020-12-15 11:39:43.1733333 | NULL |